# Decoding Actionscript ByteArray using python

Tags: python, arrays, actionscript-3, apache-flex, decode

I am using actionscript to send an array to the server with this code(I am only writing that part of the code here):-

```
var a:ByteArray=new ByteArray;
a.writeObject({'a':'b','c':'d'});
socket.writeBytes(a);
socket.flush();
```

here I already opened a socket to a port on my server and I have a python code listenting on that port. How do I decode the bytes I receive using python when I run the swf after compiling it?
I received the following in the server side:- `b'\n\x0b\x01\x03c\x06\x03d\x03a\x06\x03b\x01'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActionScript uses [AMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format) format. There is an AMF library for Python which you can use: [PyAMF](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAMF).

I got this when I tested it (with *Python 2.7*):

```
>>> import pyamf
>>> for item in pyamf.decode('\n\x0b\x01\x03c\x06\x03d\x03a\x06\x03b\x01'):
...     print item
...
{'a': u'b', 'c': u'd'}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. Any way to do this in python 3.5?

Comment: @DLN I guess so, I just did not try it.

Comment: I thought pyamf is not supported by python 3.5, I tried it before, but couldn't install it. It works fine with python 2.7.

Comment: @DLN You are right. It is not available for Python 3

Comment: You can always take the [source](https://github.com/hydralabs/pyamf) and port it to Python 3 ;)

Comment: I should probably ask this in another question, but when I use pyamf.encode({'a': u'b', 'c': u'd'}).getvalue(), I don't get back the same thing.

Comment: @DLN I think one encodes `{'a': u'b', 'c': u'd'}` and the other `{'c': u'd', 'a': u'b'}`. There is no difference in Python, but you can order them differently in AMF.

Comment: Yeah. I saw that AMF orders them that way. But I couldn't change the order in AMF. Any way to change the order when encoding using python AMF library instead?

Comment: @DLN No, it is impossible to even create a dictionary with a different order, nevermind communicating that with AMF, because `{'a': u'b', 'c': u'd'} == {'c': u'd', 'a': u'b'}`.